# Twilio callback url with node js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, twilio-api

Hello everyone i am facing problem from last few days
I have created browser dialer using Angular2 and Nodejs and to make online call i used twilio.
I have created local https url for my nodejs server it works fine. 
I have created https of my node server but when i give url as voice request url on twilio account it not make any call when i switch to ngrok it again works.
I want that my twilio account may accept my node https server url what should i do?
Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error in Twilio console?

Comment: Hey Mohammad, is the url from your node server publicly accessible? localhost for example will not work and it sounds like this is the problem.

Comment: yes, the url is publicly accesible.

Comment: Error - 11237

Certificate Invalid - Could not find path to certificate

Twilio tried to validate your SSL certificate but was unable to find it in our certificate store.

Comment: i have used purchased ssl cirtificates but twilio gives invalid cirtificates